# Infopath slow on load because of data connection to a large list

Tags: infopath

In InfoPath preview mode everything is fine, data connection on the list of 15000 items is populating dropdown menu based on a filter(I am  only looking for two rows so filtering is implanted). Once published in Central Administration, form doesn't open -it is stuck at loading.

I have inherited development of this form and there is a connection to a similar list that works in an instance(both connection strings are searching for employees attributes). Is it possible that the data connection that doesn't effect the InfoPath performance contains parameters(filters in the connection string-since the filter are not implemented on InfoPath fields)?

My connection string is killing the performance of the form.

Please help me in querying filtered values in a large list(I am not saving a copy of the list in the form).

Nemanja Sovic

Comment: Is the data connection set to 'Automatically Retrieve Data when form is loaded'?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of behind-the-scenes work InfoPath Forms Services on your SharePoint server has to do to render your form in a browser. You can tweak some performance-based settings in Central Administration, especially postback, the number of times a browser has to communicate with the server.

Rajan Kapoor offers some tweaks on how to [limit postback](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spses/archive/2015/04/07/infopath-amp-postback-settings-in-sharepoint.aspx):

> Some InfoPath form controls, actions, and features require the browser to communicate with the server during a form session. This exchange of data during the session is called a postback, and usually occurs when a form feature has to send data to the server for processing. Unnecessary postbacks impose an additional load on both the browser and the server. To protect the server, a threshold is set for the maximum number of postbacks per session. This limits the number of postbacks that can be executed during a single session when a user is filling out a form, and prevents malicious users from trying to bring down the server.

He also posts some links that allow you at the very least to understand what's going on with your form as it communicates with the server.

You can also use some web debugging tools like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to zero in on (and limit) the calls made between the browser and the server.

Comment: Is there a way to parameterize a query, so that InfoPath pulls only limited number of rows?

Comment: Have you seen this?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms772417.aspx